# Ordering images in an inline style in a list element

Tags: css

How do I order images in a list in an inline style with css? I have tried puting inline style in the list tag but it is showing it in block form. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Version2 (and without gaps in images):

In the head:

```
<style>
ul li {display: inline;} 
</style>
```

In body:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="1.gif"></li><!--  
  --><li><img src="2.gif"></li><!--  
  --><li><img src="3.gif"></li>
</ul>
```

This html comment "magic" is done because browsers interpret new line as a gap symbol between images.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to apply ".images" to the list instead of each element? Semantically more correct and less verbose. The CSS would then have to be changed to .images li.